# Roving tabindex w/ React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

What is most simple way to make "roving tabindex" in React? It's basically switch focus and `tabindex=0/-1` between child elements. Only a single element have `tabindex` of `0`, while other receives `-1`. Arrow keys switch `tabindex` between child elements, and focus it.

For now, I do a simple children mapping of required type, and set `index` prop and get `ref`, to use it later. It looks robust, but may be there more simple solution?

My current solution (pseudo-javascript, for idea illustration only):

**ElementWithFocusManagement.js**

```
function recursivelyMapElementsOfType(children, isRequiredType, getProps) {
  return Children.map(children, function(child) {
    if (isValidElement(child) === false) {return child;}

    if (isRequiredType(child)) {

      return cloneElement(
        child,
        // Return new props
        // {
        //   index, iterated in getProps closure
        //   focusRef, saved to `this.focusable` aswell, w/ index above
        // }
        getProps()
      );
    }

    if (child.props.children) {
      return cloneElement(child, {
        children: recursivelyMapElementsOfType(child.props.children, isRequiredType, getProps)
      });
    }

    return child;
  });
}

export class ElementWithFocusManagement {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Map of all refs, that should receive focus
    // {
    //   0: {current: HTMLElement}
    //   ...
    // }
    this.focusable = {};
    this.state = {
      lastInteractionIndex: 0
    };
  }

  handleKeyDown() {
    // Handle arrow keys,
    // check that element index in `this.focusable`
    // update state if it is
    // focus element
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
        <Provider value={{lastInteractionIndex: this.state.lastInteractionIndex}}>
          {recursivelyMapElementsOfType(
            children,
            isRequiredType, // Check for required `displayName` match
            getProps(this.focusable) // Get index, and pass ref, that would be saved to `this.focusable[index]`
          )}
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**with-focus.js**

```
export function withFocus(WrappedComponent) {
  function Focus({index, focusRef, ...props}) {
    return (
      <Consumer>
        {({lastInteractionIndex}) => (
          <WrappedComponent
            {...props}

            elementRef={focusRef}
            tabIndex={lastInteractionIndex === index ? 0 : -1}
          />
        )}
      </Consumer>
    );
  }

  // We will match for this name later
  Focus.displayName = `WithFocus(${WrappedComponent.name})`;

  return Focus;
}
```

**Anything.js**

```
const FooWithFocus = withFocus(Foo);

<ElementWithFocusManagement> // Like toolbar, dropdown menu and etc.
  <FooWithFocus>Hi there</FooWithFocus> // Button, menu item and etc.

  <AnythingThatPreventSimpleMapping>
    <FooWithFocus>How it's going?</FooWithFocus>
  </AnythingThatPreventSimpleMapping>

  <SomethingWithoutFocus />
</ElementWithFocusManagement>
```

Comment: Just realize, that `ElementWithFocusManagement` could be a HOC aswell

Comment: My solution will fail, if `children` gets mapped in component, mapping of `withFocus` HOCs just get failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`react-roving-tabindex`](https://github.com/stevejay/react-roving-tabindex) looks quite good.

Comment: It has some awful dependencies, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example of roving tabindex implemented in a composite widget](https://codesandbox.io/s/tc74n6), following [the recommendations from w3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#kbd_roving_tabindex):

```
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const BUTTON_NAMES = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];

export default function App() {
  const buttonRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [buttonIndex, setButtonIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [hasFocus, setHasFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const handleBlur = () => setHasFocus(false);
  const handleFocus = (index) => () => {
    setHasFocus(true);
    setButtonIndex(index);
  };
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    switch (event.code) {
      case "ArrowDown":
        setButtonIndex((prev) => Math.min(prev + 1, BUTTON_NAMES.length - 1));
        break;
      case "ArrowUp":
        setButtonIndex((prev) => Math.max(prev - 1, 0));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (hasFocus) {
      buttonRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [buttonIndex]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Roving tabindex demo</h1>
      <p>
        <button>Button outside the composite widget</button>
      </p>
      <div className={"widget" + (hasFocus ? " focus" : "")}>
        <p>Composite widget</p>
        {BUTTON_NAMES.map((name, index) => (
          <p>
            <button
              ref={index === buttonIndex ? buttonRef : null}
              tabIndex={index === buttonIndex ? 0 : -1}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onFocus={handleFocus(index)}
              onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            >
              {name}
            </button>
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
      <p>
        <button>Another button outside the composite widget</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The composite widget remembers the last focused button and allows the user to move between its buttons with `ArrowDown`, `ArrowUp` which focus the next, previous buttons.

See also the following critical points from the [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/) page:

> The visual focus indicator must always be visible.

> the tab sequence should include only one focusable element of a composite UI component. Once a composite contains focus, keys other than Tab and Shift + Tab enable the user to move focus among its focusable elements.

> When using roving tabindex to manage focus in a composite UI component, the element that is to be included in the tab sequence has tabindex of "0" and all other focusable elements contained in the composite have tabindex of "-1".